# Having a problem with loading scenes in unity3D EDITED CODE

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The player has a DontDestroyOnLoad function and I'm thinking that could be the issue because the player will delete copies of itself immediately

Alright, Heres the deal. When a player uses a door it SHOULD transport the player to another scene and then move them to the correct position and rotation. It does move to a new scene but it only occasionally moves the player to the correct position seemingly at random. How would I make this code more consistent? I'm at a loss with it.

Spawn Player Point is attached to an empty object in the world

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using StarterAssets;

public class StartPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ThirdPersonController thePlayer;
    public string lastExitName;


    private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) // use event rather than using the start method
{
    thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<ThirdPersonController>();
    if(thePlayer.nextSpawn == lastExitName)
    {
        thePlayer.transform.position = transform.position;
        Debug.Log("moved to" + thePlayer.transform.position);
        thePlayer.transform.eulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
        Debug.Log("rotated to" + thePlayer.transform.eulerAngles);
    }
}

    private void Awake()
    {
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }


   /* public void WarpPlayer()
    {
    thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<ThirdPersonController>();
    if(thePlayer.nextSpawn == lastExitName)
    {
        thePlayer.transform.position = transform.position;
        Debug.Log("moved to" + thePlayer.transform.position);
        thePlayer.transform.eulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
        Debug.Log("rotated to" + thePlayer.transform.eulerAngles);
    }
    


    }
    
    void Start()
    {   
         thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<ThirdPersonController>();
        if(thePlayer.nextSpawn == lastExitName)
        Debug.Log(thePlayer.nextSpawn);
        Debug.Log(lastExitName);
        {
        
        thePlayer.transform.position = transform.position;
        Debug.Log("moved location to " + thePlayer.transform.position);
        thePlayer.transform.eulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
        Debug.Log("moved rotation to " + thePlayer.transform.eulerAngles);
        }
        
    }*/
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
          Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Vector3 direction = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 5;
        Gizmos.DrawRay(transform.position, direction);
    }

}
```

This loads the new area

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using StarterAssets;


public class LoadNewLevel : MonoBehaviour
{  
    
    public string levelToLoad;
    public string exitName;
    private StartPoint startPoint;

    private ThirdPersonController thePlayer;
    void Awake()
    {
        startPoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SpawnPoint").GetComponent<StartPoint>();

        thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<ThirdPersonController>();

        
    }

   
    public void MoveLevel()
    {
        thePlayer.nextSpawn = exitName;
        Debug.Log("set Spawn to" + thePlayer.nextSpawn);
        //PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastExitName", exitName);
        
        
        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
        Debug.Log("sceneloaded" + levelToLoad);
        //startPoint.WarpPlayer();

    }

}
```

the managing the players next spawn is managed in the player controller and is just a simple public string.

Comment: I feel quite stupid for this, but the solution was to Auto Sync Transforms in the project settings. It works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SceneManager.sceneLoaded event to ensure that the player is moved to the correct position after the new scene is fully loaded. The issue might be that things are happening before the scene is fully loaded?

```
private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) // use event rather than using the start method
{
    thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<ThirdPersonController>();
    if(thePlayer.nextSpawn == lastExitName)
    {
        thePlayer.transform.position = point.transform.position;
        thePlayer.transform.eulerAngles = point.transform.eulerAngles;
    }
}

private void Awake()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
}
```

Another thing I would suggest is to make use of Debug.Log()! It would be super helpful to place a Debug.Log() line after each chunk (if not each line) of code. This way you'll be able to make sure everything is being called correctly and in the right order.

It would be very interesting if you could Debug.Log() the player and the point position and rotation; It might be that the point position is off, who knows!

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I added some logs and as far as I can tell its going in the correct order, Used the Door, Set Spawn to point, changed scene, then moved the player to new location. It seems that the issue is that its moving the player to the correct space and THEN moving them back to where they were before in world space.