# Player transform.position not working on collider but if statement is getting called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make a checkpoint system but player.transform.position is not working. I know if the statement is working because Debug.Log("Hello") is coming in console. I am trying to make a checkpoint system in which if the player falls off the platform and collides with the trigger attached below script it will get teleported back to platform. No error message coming just Hello Debug. I am also using first person template from unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject player;
        public GameObject respawnPoints;
    
        private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                Debug.Log("Hello");
                player.transform.position = respawnPoints.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
```

The above script is attached to box cube with mesh renderer off,  box collider with is trigger ticked.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Checkpoint_1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Respawn respawn;

    [SerializeField] private Animator playAnimation;

    private void Awake()
    {
        respawn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Respawn").GetComponent<Respawn>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playAnimation.SetBool("CheckpointTrigger", true);
            respawn.respawnPoint = this.gameObject;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any null reference errors after `Hello` log ? Also make sure you have assigned correct game objects from the inspector.

Comment: no, nothing just hello debug log

Comment: "respawnPoint*s*" indicates to me that there is more than one respawn point. Are you sure you are referencing to the correct point?

Comment: yes, respawnpoints get automatically assigned once I reach first checkpoint. I even tried to preassign it but no luck. I will upload that script as well just in case

Comment: Sound like it could be a similar issue to this, where the physics takes priority and essentially ignores your `player.transform.position = respawnPoints.transform.position`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75441149/21121257 This will make sure that if you move the transform, the physics system will also update. Here is a link to the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-autoSyncTransforms.html

Comment: Another solution would be to set a bool to true in the `OnTriggerEnter` (call the bool something like `movePlayer`). Then, have a `private void FixedUpdate()` method. In it you should check `if(movePlayer)` and set the `player.transform.position` and set `movePlayer = false`. I think this would solve the issue as you are meant to make any changes to physics objects within the `FixedUpdate`

Comment: Whenever physics is involved do not set anything through `Transform` but rather the `Rigidbody` like e.g. `player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = respawnPoints.transform.position` .. also are you sure that `respawn` is referencing the correct object?

Comment: Is this a 3D game and is there a NavMeshAgent on the player? If so you should use the Warp method (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.Warp.html) or disable/enable NavMeshAgent before/after doing the operation. NavMeshAgent and directly changing transform position don't go well together.

Comment: holy shit it worked !! Thanks guys I have been so disturbed due to this. Thanks a lot